# Changing the mode of excel online to edit in Sharepoint using Power automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, power-automate

As shown in the below pic I need to change the mode of excel online from view to edit in SharePoint using Power automate.
[image]

Can we use send an HTTP request option to SharePoint in power automate flow?If yes,please let me know how.

Thanks,
Freshy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viewing your screenshot, i did notice the below message:

[image]

Have you tried the below?

[SharePoint files open as read-only](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/files-open-as-read-only-and-cannot-check-in-or-out)